# for interprocess communication, from the below which technique is used

Tags: parallel-processing, theory, message

messaging passing

or

remote procedure call

irrespective of the architecture or not?

Comment: What is your reason for leaving out out "shared memory"?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can use either for inter process communication on most systems without much trouble at all. Often message passing can be implemented with less overheads, but that tends to be system specific.